# Change text dependant on range value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a range input such as the below:

```
<input type="range" value="5" name="mySlider" min="1" max="5"/>
```

The default value is 5, it goes from 1 to 5. I want to add text to the side which changes depending on what the slider is currently at. I'm not too well versed in Javascript, my best attempt doesn't produce an appropriate result:

```
<input type="range" onChange="updateSlider();" value="5" id="slide" name="mySlider" min="1" max="5"/>
<span id="sliderChange"></span>

function updateSlider() {
    var value = $("#slide").val();
    if (value == 1) {
        $("#sliderChange").text("One");
    } elseif (value == 2) {
        $("#sliderChange").text("Two");
    } elseif (value == 3) {
        $("#sliderChange").text("Three");
    } elseif (value == 4) {
        $("#sliderChange").text("Four");
    } else {
        $("#sliderChange").text("Five");
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, something kind of unrelated: I personally haven't seen range inputs since the late 90s. Are these still a thing?

Comment: Have you tried `if (value == "1")`, etc? It might be the case due to the use of `input type="range"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in writing `elseif` instead of `else if`, but again, a `switch` statement might be more appropriate and readable.

With the new web standards and semantic HTML we discourage using inline on* bindings and style information (style property), the JS, HTML and CSS should be self-contained.
Seeing that you already use jQuery, you can use the jQuery `change` and `input` events to seperate JS and HTML.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#slide").on( "change input", function () {
       var value = $(this).val();
       if (value == 1) {
          $("#sliderChange").text("One");
       }
       else if (value == 2) {
          $("#sliderChange").text("Two");
       }
       else if (value == 3) {
          $("#sliderChange").text("Three");
       }
       else if (value == 4) {
          $("#sliderChange").text("Four");
       }
       else {
          $("#sliderChange").text("Five");
       }
    });
 });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/47qKt/3/)

You need `input` because `change` is only triggered when the mouse is realeased, but IE only  supports `change` so you best use both.

Comment: Cheers. Your Fiddle is very nice, thanks! While the Fiddle works perfectly, on my machine in WAMP it does not. I guess this is a problem I must solve before I do any more Jquery.

Comment: Are you sure that jQuery is included properly and that the script is run after the inclusion?

Answer (score 1):

you code can be rewritten as (using `mousemove` event instaed of `change` event and using unobtrusive javascript)

**HTML**
    `<input type="range" value="5" id="slide" name="mySlider" min="1" max="5" />`
    `<span id="sliderChange"></span>`

**Javascript**

```
     $(function () {
        function updateSlider() {
           var value = $("#slide").val();
           if (value == 1) {
              $("#sliderChange").text("One");
           }
           else if (value == 2) {
              $("#sliderChange").text("Two");
           }
           else if (value == 3) {
              $("#sliderChange").text("Three");
           }
           else if (value == 4) {
              $("#sliderChange").text("Four");
           }
           else {
              $("#sliderChange").text("Five");
           }
        }

        $('#slide').mousemove(updateSlider);
     });
```

You could also use `switch` statement instead of `if/else`

Answer (score 1):

In your code you use `elseif`, in javascript it's `else if`.

You also should use `mousemove` instead of `change`

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47qKt/1/) to make it easier for you

Comment: Why would you use `mousemove` over `change input`? It only spams the browser with events that slow it down.

Comment: @S0lll0s while change is good is most cases, it'll wait for a `mouseup` event before running the function. mousemove does it in realtime (as does input). And with current technology, I don't really think you would  notice any slowing.